# How to migrate an OS X guest VM to a physical machine?

Tags: macos, time-machine, backup, parallels-desktop

I am running OS X Yosemite, and Parallels 10.

I have a guest VM running OS X Yosemite. I would like to migrate the guest VM to a physical machine. Is this possible? The reason is that the guest vm is just too slow, and I would be better off running on a physical machine. I have a number of developer tools installed and configured perfectly on the VM that would take a long time to download them on the physical machine. Thats why I just want to "migrate" to a physical machine.

I tried connecting an external hard drive to the VM, and creating a time machine backup, but it fails to even make the initial backup. The error message is:

"An error occurred while copying files. The problem may be temporary. If the problem persists use disk utility to repair your backup disk"

Comment: Why don't you copy the .app files and other dev tools to the disk?

Comment: Because that isn't enough - the tools set up a number of environment variables, and install a number of other files outside the app. It isn't apparent what additional files they create.

Answer (score 2):

Use [SuperDuper](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) or [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com/) to create a bootable image
to an external or internal disk. SuperDuper can also be used for free.

Comment: When setting up a new mac, OS X warns you to use migration assistant (instead of setting up from a time machine backup), if you are setting up a machine with different hardware, than from the one which you backed up, the reason being different hardware uses different drivers etc. By doing a carbon copy clone I could create a number of new problems because the hardware is different.

Comment: @John Although it became somewhat less convenient on recent releases of OSX, it usually comes "batteries included". Normally it is no problem to boot on different hardware (provided it is compatible). I sometimes take my MacBook's internal SSD and boot it via USB on my much older Mac mini. Only some preferences mey get reset due to different UUIDs, etc. Also Parallels complains. Anyway you can try without any risk.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using [SuperDuper](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) or [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com/) to create a bootable image
to an external or internal disk, you could also Disk Utility in OS X to either create an image or clone the mounted virtual hard drive to a disk.  If creating an image with Disk Utility you'd need to use the Scan Image for Restore... command from the Image menu in Disk Utility before restoring the image.

Obviously regardless of what App or method you choose it will be a multi-step process if the source resides on the target disk.

If you have any worries about the virtual disk install running on physical Apple-branded hardware then cloning the virtual card drive to an external USB drive will allow you to boot the Apple-branded hardware from the clone to see that all will be well before overwriting the internal drive with the contents of the virtual hard disk.

It should work okay as I've done it in the past with VMware Fusion OS X virtual hard disks and Disk Utility images between different Macs of different hardware builds without issues.